# Load and no-load current of a DC motor

Tags: brushed-dc-motor

My DC motor has no-load current of 60 mA max and load Current of 300 mA max. What does that mean?

Comment: Do you understand what *load* means?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no prior research done before posting and the question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The no-load current is the current required just to turn the motor shaft with nothing connected. It is the current required to overcome the bearing and brush friction plus the aerodynamic drag caused by the rotor moving in the air and moving air through the motor for cooling purposes.

The maximum load current is the maximum continuous current that can be used to continuously drive a load, If the current is higher than that, the motor will run too hot and the insulation will fail eventually. Exceeding the maximum load current slightly will reduce the lifetime of the motor slightly. Exceeding the maximum load current by a lot will cause the motor to fail quickly.

It is also important to understand the locked (or blocked) rotor current. That is the level of current that flows when the motor is not turning. If the motor is started by simply switching it on at full voltage, the locked rotor current flows initially. As the rotor accelerates, the current declines to a lower level. The time that the locked rotor current normally flows is very brief and not harmful to a small motor. To avoid damage, motors rated higher than a few hundred watts require a reduced-voltage starting method to limit the starting current.

Answer (score 0):

At the rated voltage with the motor spinning freely and not driving any load (No Load) at all it will draw 0.06 amps. At the rated voltage, when it is turning a load which strains the motor to it's maximum level, the motor will draw 0.3 amps (Load Current). The motor draws more current when it has to work hard.